# CountDown Timer not Working

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, time

I am trying to implement [this circular timer](http://git.wimbarelds.nl/TimeCircles/readme.php) on product Detail page 
by following the instructions.

my **catalog_product_view.xml** code is

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <link type="text/javascript" src_type="url" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"/>
    <link src="Vendor_module::js/TimeCircles.js"/>
    <css src="Vendor_module::css/TimeCircles.css"/>
</head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.stock.sku" >
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\Banner" name="timers_product" 
                   template="Vendor_module::product/timer.phtml" after="product.info.stock" />
        </referenceBlock>

    </body>
</page>
```

my **timer.phtml** code is

```
<div class="example" data-date="2014-01-01 00:00:00"></div>

    <script>
        require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){

            var id_flash = "2";
            var _days   = "Days";
            var _hours  = "Hours";
            var _mins   = "Minutes";
            var _secs   = "Seconds";
            var _color1 = '#90989F';
            var _color2 = '#40484F';

            if ("#FF3939" != '')
                _color1 = "#FF3939";
            if ("#ffc3d0" != '')
                _color2 = "#ffc3d0";
            // Circle Counter
            $(function() {
                $('#example').TimeCircles({
                    "animation": "smooth",
                    "bg_width": 0.3,
                    "fg_width": 0.06,
                    "circle_bg_color":_color2,
                    "text_size": 0.11,
                    "time": {
                        "Days": {
                            "text": _days,
                            "color": _color1,
                            "show": true
                        },
                        "Hours": {
                            "text": _hours,
                            "color": _color1,
                            "show": true
                        },
                        "Minutes": {
                            "text": _mins,
                            "color": _color1,
                            "show": true
                        },
                        "Seconds": {
                            "text": _secs,
                            "color": _color1,
                            "show": true
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

> I'm getting this Error in console

```
>Uncaught TypeError: $(...).TimeCircles is not a function
>at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (push-it-messenger-bag.html:815)
>at fire (jquery.js:3232)
>at Object.add [as done] (jquery.js:3291)
>at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.ready (jquery.js:3542)
>at jQuery.fn.init (jquery.js:2967)
>at new jQuery.fn.init (jquery-migrate.js:225)
>at jQuery (jquery.js:75)
>at push-it-messenger-bag.html:814
>at Object.execCb (require.js:1650)
>at Module.check (require.js:866)
```

My Directory Structure

```
->Vendor
  |-->Module
   |-->view
    |-->frontend
      |-->templates
        |-->product
          |-->timer.phtml
      |-->web
        |-->css
          |-->TimeCircles.css
        |-->js
          |-->TimeCircles.js
```

Comment: do you also have `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tried your code, it is working for me after below modification.

=> **Remove** `<link type="text/javascript" src_type="url" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"/>` from `catalog_product_view.xml` because we already have jQuery

=> **Change** from `class` to `Id` in `timer.phtml`, because JS searching for Id, like

```
 <div id="example" data-date="2014-01-01 00:00:00"></div>
```

=> Please check after changing above 2 point. If still there is error you need to change in TimeCircles.js

```
1 Change first line from (function($) { to require(['jquery'],function($){

2 Change last line from }(jQuery)); to });
```